# Java applet click on image and do something

Tags: java, applet

how can i click on a image in a java applet and then it will do something?

Like i like on the image then it will do a System.out.print or something?

Comment: I think you will find that people are more likely to spend time helping you if you spend at least an equal time describing what you want help with. Read your question and then try to imagine how anyone but yourself is going to understand what it is you are having difficulties with.

Answer (score 1):

You should go through this tutorial on how to use the MouseAdapter class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all extend `applet` and `MouseListener` with your class:

```
public class MouseClickClass extends Applet implements MouseListener
{
```

Then add these methods and do whatever you like inside them:

```
 public void mousePressed (MouseEvent me) {
   // Do something here
   repaint();
 }

 public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent me) {
   // Do something here
   repaint();
 } 

 public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent me) {
   // Do something here
   repaint();
 }
```

Comment: Alternatively, write your own Component that contains the image (and fits the image's exact boundaries) and make that implement a MouseListener. That way if the image moves around the screen, you don't need to worry about the location.